# Powershell return next word after search string

Tags: powershell

My apologies if this is a duplicate but I have searched in vain. I'm trying to return **inclusive** the proceeding word after the search-string in powershell.

```
$wordtest="one two three four"
```

How does one simply extract **inclusive** `two three`?

I have attempted with futility:

```
$wordtest.substring($wordtest.IndexOf('two') +1)
```

and

```
($wordtest.Split('two')[1])
```

I have the **exclusive** `three` query working by using:

```
(($wordtest -split "two")[1].trim() -split ' ')[0]
 three
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use Regular Expression for this:

```
$wordtest   = "one two three four"
$searchWord = "two"
if ($wordtest -match "($searchWord\s+\w+)") {
    $matches[0]
}
```

**Result**

> two three

Mind you that if `$searchWord` contains special characters for Regex, like `.` or `$` for instance, you need to `[Regex]::Escape($searchWord)` first.

**Special Characters in Regex**

```
Char    Description                         Meaning
------- ----------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------
\       Backslash                           Used to escape a special character
^       Caret                               Beginning of a string
$       Dollar sign                         End of a string
.       Period or dot                       Matches any single character
|       Vertical bar or pipe symbol         Matches previous OR next character/group
?       Question mark                       Match zero or one of the previous
*       Asterisk or star                    Match zero, one or more of the previous
+       Plus sign                           Match one or more of the previous
( )     Opening and closing parenthesis     Group characters
[ ]     Opening and closing square bracket  Matches a range of characters
{ }     Opening and closing curly brace     Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to do three things:

- Split a string into words
- Find the word you're interested in
- Get the next word

so let's do that:

```bsh
$wordtest = "one two three four"
$searchWord = "two";

# split a string into words
$words = $wordtest.Split(" ");

# find the word you're interested in
$wordIndex = $words.IndexOf($searchWord);

# get the next word
$nextWord = $words[$wordIndex + 1];
```

This is very simplistic code - for example it treats each space character as a word break, so multiple spaces (and tabs) will cause problems (e.g. `one     two     three     four`), it doesn't have proper error handling for if you *don't* find your word, and it will raise exceptions if there isn't a "next word".

In any case, once you've got the search word and the next word, you can construct your "inclusive" and "exclusive" strings...

```bsh
$inclusive = "$searchWord $nextWord";
$exclusive = $nextWord;
```